# Magento 2 How to display custom text instead of shipping method title and carrier title

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, shipping-methods, localisation, totals

How to display only "Shipping" text instead of "Shipping(Flat Rate - Fixed)" text in Cart, Checkout and Emails.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string "Flat Rate - Fixed" is generated based on the shipping method configuration in `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage::saveShippingMethod()`:

```
$shippingDescription = $rate->getCarrierTitle() . ' - ' . $rate->getMethodTitle();
$shippingAddress->setShippingDescription(trim($shippingDescription, ' -'));
```

Later, it is appended to "Shipping" in `\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Address\Attribute\Frontend\Shipping::fetchTotals()`:

```
$title = __('Shipping & Handling');
if ($address->getShippingDescription()) {
    $title .= sprintf(' (%s)', $address->getShippingDescription());
}
```

As you can see, if `getShippingDescription()` is empty, nothing is added (i.e. no empty brackets), so you can get your desired result by unsetting the shipping description.

```
$address->setShippingDescription('');
```

This can be done in several places, IMHO the best option is to do it right before the shipping address is saved:

- using the event `sales_quote_address_save_before` ***OR***
- using a "before" plugin for `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::save()`

Answer (score 2):

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
        <plugin name="disable-freeshipping" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;

class Freeshipping
{
    protected $tablerate;

    protected $_resultMethodFactory;

    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate $tablerate,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $resultMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->tablerate = $tablerate;
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_resultMethodFactory = $resultMethodFactory;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function aroundCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $freeshipping, \Closure $proceed, $request)
    {
        // $resTableRate = $this->tablerate->collectRates($request);
        // foreach ($resTableRate->getAllRates() as $rate) {
        //     if ($rate->getMethod()) {
        //          return false;
        //     }
        // }

        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            $items = $request->getAllItems();
            $yourSkus = array('your sku');
            $isExist = false;
            foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
                if(in_array($item->getSku(),$yourSkus)) {
                    $isExist = true;
                    $normalItemCheck = false;
                }
            }

            $title = '';
            $name ='';
            if($isExist) {
                $title ='Free Shipping';
                $name ='Item will ship (10-14 days)';
            }

            if($name != '' || $title != '') {
                $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
                $method = $this->_resultMethodFactory->create();
                $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
                $method->setCarrierTitle($title);

                $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
                $method->setMethodTitle($name);

                $method->setPrice('0.00');
                $method->setCost('0.00');

                $result->append($method);
                return $result;
            }
        }
        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for changing the visible text. Here are two clear options.

- Magento's translation system. I will direct you to the [M2 Developer Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html). Essentially, you will create a .csv file in a special location. This will let you make statements like `"Shipping (Flat Rate - Fixed)","Shipping"`, instructing Magento to replace every occurrence of the left string with the right string.
- In your theme, override the .phtml template that contains the string. Again, I will direct you to [Magento's M2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-overview.html) on adding templates to your theme. Once you have a working theme, if you include a .phtml at the correct location, Magento will use your template instead of the parent theme's template.

Comment: While this is true for most texts in Magento, here it does not work. These values are built dynamically in the shipping carrier models (the implementations of `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierInterface::collectRates()`), based on the **configured** carrier title ("Flat Rate") and method title ("Fixed"). There is no translation involved and no template contains the string.

Answer (score 0):

**1. vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
        <plugin name="shipping_title_update" type="vendor\module\Plugin\FreeShipping"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2. vendor\module\Plugin\FreeShipping.php**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Plugin;

use Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping as OriginalFreeShipping;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class FreeShipping
{
    /** @var Session|\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * FreeShipping constructor.
     *
     * @param Session                              $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $backendQuoteSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State         $state
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session      $customerSession
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $backendQuoteSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        if ($state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
            $this->session = $backendQuoteSession;
        } else {
            $this->session = $checkoutSession;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param OriginalFreeShipping $subject
     * @param callable             $proceed
     * @param                      $field
     * @return float
     */
    public function aroundGetConfigData(OriginalFreeShipping $subject, callable $proceed, $field)
    {
        $value = $proceed($field);
        if ($field == 'title') {
            $value ='Method Title ';
        }

        if ($field == 'name') {
            $value ='method Name ';
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```