# How to enable Flat Rate Shipping Method Only for Selected Products?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

How to do the Flat Rate Shipping Method only for selected products.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151701/magento-2-how-to-display-custom-text-instead-of-shipping-method-title-and-carrie/344627#344627

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using some extension . For instance this extension would help you.

https://www.mconnectmedia.com/magento-flat-rate-shipping-per-product.html

https://plugin.company/blog/configuring-shipping-rates-per-product-in-magento/

Comment: Is there any free stuff or anything do with code?