# Need to override \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping

Tags: magento2

I need to override the `collectRates()` function in file **(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping)** file.

I want to hide `CarrierTitle & MethodTitle` on the checkout page so I am planning pass set blank `CarrierTitle & MethodTitle` for that I need to override **collectRates() function**

Comment: why you need to set  `CarrierTitle` and `CarrierTitle` bank?

Comment: In case of free shipping I want to hide CarrierTitle and CarrierTitle & instead of $0.00 i want to change text to Free Shipping.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151701/magento-2-how-to-display-custom-text-instead-of-shipping-method-title-and-carrie/344627#344627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overide that file you need to do following things.

1. create `di.xml` file at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" />
</config>
```

2. now create the `Freeshipping.php` at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier;

    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

    class Freeshipping extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping
    {
        public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
        {
            // Do your logic here
        }

    }
```

Comment: how can i override  $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

Comment: Check my answer, you have already overide entire function. so here you need to put what every you want instade of that one.

Comment: I have used the same method which you gave but I am getting error of blank value being retuned from this getConfigData() which was defined in Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier file so do I need to include that 2

Comment: if you have new question then ask seprately, so other can also reply you. hope you understand.