# Magento 2 How to display custom text instead of shipping method title and carrier

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout

how to change the title of flat rate -fixed to Shipping

[image]

Comment: what text exactly you want to change ..you want to change particular method title or you need to remove whole selected text to some other text whatever shipping method is

Comment: i want to remove (Flat Rate -Fixed) From Cart Summary

Comment: yes but for all shipping method ?

Comment: no only for slate rate fixed

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151701/magento-2-how-to-display-custom-text-instead-of-shipping-method-title-and-carrie/344627#344627

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/totals/shipping.js
```

- this path is for cart page only override this file in your theme and 
  change this

```
getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
            return '(custom title)';
        }
```

Comment: but that title change from all site i am changing only one

Comment: check I have edited my answer

Comment: `pub/static` folder is a temporary folder it will regenerate on every `static-content-deploy` it is not recommended at all to make changes inside the `pub/static` files.

Comment: @SanjibChowdhury : I already mentioned that you need to override above file

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the code 
`vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html` and `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html`

you need to override these files in your theme and do the necessary changes on that.

Function `getShippingMethodTitle()` is responsible to show the name over there.

Comment: can you please guide me how the getShippingMethodTitle()

Comment: the function is in `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.js` please go and check.

Comment: how to remove the (Flate Rate -Fixed) from cart summary simple

Comment: remove `getShippingMethodTitle()` function call from `tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html` and `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html`